# Find and replace query in SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to change my name column records like if the name is with one word (Example: John) it should remain same (Ex: John). If it is with two words (Ex: John Bodi) it should be there as it is (Ex: John Bodi) but if it is one word and one letter (Ex:John B) then it should get '.' at the end of the letter(Ex: John B.)
Please post your query for this. It helps me.

Table is likes as

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.tblNames 
(
    ID int,
    FName varchar(25),
    LName varchar(25)
) 
GO

INSERT INTO tblNames 
     VALUES (1, 'John', 'Bodi')
INSERT INTO tblNames 
     VALUES (2, 'Jack', 'B')
INSERT INTO tblNames 
     VALUES (3, 'S', 'Fry')
INSERT INTO tblNames 
     VALUES (4, 'H', 'M')
GO
```

Comment: Why not insert it like `Jack B.` at the beginning?

Comment: @ Max I want to update already inserted Data .

Comment: I think it would be easier to modify the records in C# and update them from there.

Comment: @ max Have you any idea what will be code ? either in C# or Sql

Comment: C# wouldn't be that hard, using String.Substring will do the trick I think http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx or a Regex.

Comment: depending on what you need to show, you can have 2 types of data, the one that you save, and the one that you show. the physical data would be [1,John,Bodi] and the logical data(the one showing after the logic of just the first letter) would be 'John B.' where the select would require to have your Lname just get the first letter(if there is data on the Lname) and append a "." to it

Comment: @Poncho thanks but  for ID 2 i want to update Last Name "B" to "B." This is my concern.and for ID 3 i want to update "s" to "s."  Kindly again read my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your comment and got an answer

```
UPDATE tblNames SET 
    FName = CASE WHEN LEN(FName) = 1 THEN (FName + '.') ELSE FName END,
    LName = CASE WHEN LEN(LName) = 1 THEN (LName + '.') ELSE LName END
GO
```

Can you Judge me This is a good way or not to solve this.